# Strange heroku command error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, command

When I run any heroku command or open a page where user is not signed in. This is the only error I'm getting over and over again.

I did remove the Heroku tmp today but I pushed the app fine afterwards, the error suddenly happened.

**When i go to the app it opens up if the user is signed in but when opened incognito it has an error, checking the logs it's the same error below**

Can anyone help me out on this one?

```
module.js:491
throw err;

Error: Cannot find module 'universalify'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.local/share/heroku/client/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js:3:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
module.js:491
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'universalify'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.local/share/heroku/client/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js:3:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
 !    error getting commands pid 14405 exit 1
```

Comment: Apparently, there is a missing package. Could you check your package.json content?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to package.json and rebuild instanses:

```
"universalify": "^0.1.1"
```

or run this command on your server and restart node.js:

```
npm install universalify --save
```

Answer (score 1):

I will advice you run these on your terminal in your CWD of the preoject `npm uninstall universalify -S --save`, which should remove any form of `universalify` that probably had some missing dependencies during your `npm install`, after which you can then run `npm install universalify --save`.

Don't hesitate to comment if you encounter any further challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this error last time when i'm still doing my project on node . So what i did was . Install every npm that is missing so something like this

`npm install universalify --save`

If it still persist. Delete the folder of the universalify and reinstall npm again :) . And don't forget to delete it also on your package.json